# Prevent XSL loop from printing every value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I need to get the `servtypes` and `servamt` value when `servtypes` is equal to "Service 3". I used the XSL logic and it somehow gets the "Service 3" and its corresponding amount.

XSL Code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="service">
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="14pt" display-align="center">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:if test="servtypes='Service 3'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="servtypes"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" >
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:if test="servtypes='Service 3'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="servamt"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="14pt" display-align="center">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:leader/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

XML Example

```
<charges>
    <fees>25</fees>
    <desc>Description</desc>
    <service>
        <servtypes>Service 1</servtypes>
        <servamt>150</servamt>
    </service>
    <service>
        <servtypes>Service 2</sertypes>
        <servamt>10</servamt>
    </service>
    <service>
        <servtypes>Service 3</servtypes>
        <servamt>150</servamt>
    </service>
<charges>
```

The problem is that whenever it loops through different values of service it also creates table row for each service that doesn't match and the cell contains blank values see the table below. 

How do I prevent creation of blank rows and cells and just create a table whose value matches only the Service 3?

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Blank</td>
 <td>Blank</td>
 <td>Blank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Blank</td>
 <td>Blank</td>
 <td>Blank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Service 3</td>
 <td>Service Value</td>
 <td>Service</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I was able to make this work check xsl below. 
**Solution**

```
<xsl:for-each select="service">
    <xsl:if test="servtypes='Service 3'">
        <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-top="2pt" padding-left="14pt" padding-bottom="2pt" display-align="center">
            <fo:block>
                Amount
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-top="2pt" text-align="left" padding-bottom="2pt">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="servamt"/>
        </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-top="2pt" padding-left="14pt" padding-bottom="2pt" display-align="center">
        <fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The third snippet is a HTML table. But the XSLT code produces XSL-FO markup. Please clarify.

Comment: @mzjn yes it is but am just trying to illustrate the output in table format as it is easy to desribe. Just run the code snippet so it will show the table.

Comment: I think it is confusing. The question has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: @mzjn the result/output i wanted to show is in tabular format but since in SO i can't make table as easily as in excel i had to create a simple table using html just so that i can describe the output of my xslt code.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: *don't match what you don't need!*

In the following code I put the matching expression in the `xsl:template match=""` rule and excluded the rest of the `text()` from matching. I also removed the `xsl:if`s.

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />    

<xsl:template match="/charges">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="service" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="service[servtypes='Service 3']">    
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="14pt" display-align="center">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="servtypes"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" >
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="servamt"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="14pt" display-align="center">
            <fo:block>
                <fo:leader/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks for helping out. I tried the code you answered but i get this error xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet.

Comment: Have a look at [an example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_templates.asp) to see where to place `xsl:template` elements in your stylesheet.